# Transferring to another Ph.D. program

Tags: phd, application, transfer-student

I came here to ask some questions regarding transferring to another Ph.D. program.

I am in a top-tier Stat Ph.D. program, under a well-known advisor. However, security problems keep becoming more serious in my college town and I'm afraid that one day my personal security will be compromised. Therefore, I intend to transfer to another school B (from which I had an offer from three different professors in the past). My program does not require attending a lab or any in-person activity. I am still a first-year student.

My questions are:

1. Is this a common reason for program transferring?
2. Will my transfer have a higher success probability because I used to have an offer from school B?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: How well do you understand the situation in the town B is in?

Comment: Good sugg, I will learn more about it.